# the output of the code in the text file is weird characters and it should be names and numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class admin {
   public:
    string ID;
    string any;
    string Name;
    string librarian;
    void getdata();
    void showdata();
    void adddata();
    void displaydata();
};
void admin::getdata() {
    ofstream file_obj;
    file_obj.open("Students.txt", ios::app);
    admin obj;
    string id;
    string name;
    string lib;
    cout << "Enter Student Details......\n\n";
    cout << "Enter ID No.     : ";
    cin >> ID;
    cout << "Enter Full Name         : ";
    cin >> Name;
    cout << "Enter librarian name.     : ";
    cin >> librarian;
    obj.ID = id;
    obj.Name = name;
    obj.librarian = lib;
    file_obj.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
}
void admin::showdata() {
    ifstream file_obj;
    file_obj.open("Students.txt", ios::in);
    admin obj;
    string id;
    string name;
    string lib;
    obj.ID = id;
    obj.Name = name;
    obj.librarian = lib;
    file_obj.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));

    cout << "\n\n.......Student Details......\n";
    cout << "ID No.     : " << ID << endl;
    cout << "Full Name         : " << Name << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << " librarian name.     : " << librarian << endl;
}

int main() {
    admin myobj;
    myobj.getdata();
    myobj.showdata();
}
```

The output of the code in the text file is weird characters and it should be names and numbers, I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Please do not pad your question to bypass the filters.

Comment: Search for "serialization" online. The way you're doing it simply doesn't work. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Because `admin` has a non-trivially copyable member (`std::string`) then it is also not trivially copyable. So it is not compatible with `file_obj.write`. You need to write each member individually to the file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
file_obj.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
```

Your class admin contains objects that include pointers to other objects. You save the address of these pointers to your file.

```
file_obj.read((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj));
```

But when you reload the object, you make no effort to fix these pointers (the address where they are pointing could now point at something completely different).

Note: Overwriting objects like this (anything non trivial) is technically Illegal. The only valid way of creating or updating a complex object like a string is via its method on the API. Just writing over the object basically is invalid and not allowed.

```
string Name;
```

Technically the type `std::string` could contain anything (you have no idea). But let us assume for argument that it has three pointers in it.

These point at an area of memory that contain the string data. But when you read the object from file what is in that area of memory now. Also the actual implementation of `std::string` could change between platform and/or version of compiler (so it could have a different size).